# Unable to migrate questions

Tags: support, migration

I appear to have lost the ability to vote to move [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950311/small-linux-live-distribution) to superuser.com. I can see the first five close reasons (exact duplicate, off-topic, subjective and argumentative, not a real question, too localized), but I'm missing any migration options. I currently have 11 votes remaining.

Can the rest of you still vote to migrate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click "Off topic", you'll get a list.  You'll have to tap your foot a few times.

Comment: Huh. I must have missed that UI change. Thanks.